# Read a partitioned parquet dataset from multiple files with PyArrow and add a partition key based on the filename

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I have a bunch of `parquet` files, each containing a subset of my dataset. Let's say that the files are named `data-N.parquet` with `N` being an integer.

I can read them all and subsequently convert to a `pandas` dataframe:

```
files = glob.glob("data-**.parquet")
ds = pq.ParquetDataset(
    files,
    metadata_nthreads=64,
).read_table(use_threads=True)
df = ds.to_pandas()
```

This works just fine. What it would like to have is an additional column in the final data frame, indicating from which file the data is originating.

As far as I understand, the `ds` data is partitioned, with one partition per file. So it would be a matter of including the partition key in the data frame.

Is this feasible?

Comment: This seems like it would make for a good JIRA if it is a feature that will be useful to you.  Most of the ground work is there to enable the feature.

Comment: @Pace Thanks for the suggestion, here it is : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-14176 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The partition key is, at the moment, included in the dataframe.  However, all existing partitioning schemes use directory names for the key.  So if your data was `/N/data.parquet` or `/batch=N/data.parquet` this will happen (you will need to supply a partitioning object when you read the dataset).

There is no way today (in pyarrow) to get the filename in the returned results.